# How to filter Facebook pages by CREATE_CONTENT permission?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have the following Graph API call: `me/accounts?fields=access_token,name,id,perms` that I use to get the page tokens from the user.

Now I would like to filter this by `perms="CREATE_CONTENT"`. *How can I filter this Graph API call?*

I'm using the [C# Facebook.net SDK](http://facebooksdk.net/). Currently I use this code:

`client.Post("me/accounts", new { fields = "access_token,name,id,perms" });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening caveat: I do *not* know C#, but I regularly work with the Facebook in other programming languages.

Facebook has a number of ["Publish Permissions"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) as part of its Extended Permissions. I'm assuming you're already requesting one or more of these permissions from your users. (I don't see a `create_content` listed; that's the only reason I mention it.) Let's say, for example, you requested the `create_event` permission from your users.

Try accumulating the Facebook User IDs into a list, and then issuing a FQL query using the Facebook SDK client for the permission(s) you're interested in:

```
List<int> facebookUserIds = new List<int>(1, 2, 3);
var query = string.Format("SELECT uid, create_event FROM permissions WHERE uid IN ({})", string.Join(",", facebookUserIds));

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.q = query;
dynamic results = client.Get("/fql", parameters);
```

The response you receive will have properties like this (here, in JSON format):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 1, 
      "create_event": 1
    },
    {
      "uid": 2, 
      "create_event": 0
    }
    {
      "uid": 3, 
      "create_event": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, `0` means permission denied, and `1` means permission granted for the App ID you're using to authenticate with the Facebook API.

Note: Users will only be returned in the response if they've previously authenticated your app (of the most basic level of permissions); but this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly filter this in the API, but it would be quite easy to do from c#- you're getting an ICollection from the Facebook.JSONObject response, so you can just use linq to filter it - [Filtering collections in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp) has a pretty good explanation of how to achieve this.

Comment: You won't be able to see the page access token if you do that.