# Pruning List of Times During the Day to Remove Times in the Past

Tags: c#, wpf

In a C# / WPF application I have a list of type string that is the ItemsSource of a combobox. This list contains half-hour chunks of time that are free on the user's calendar for the current day (from 8am to 5pm). Pictured here:

[image]

I would like to trim the list so that times in the past are not shown (e.g. If it's presently 10am, don't show chunks of time from 8am-10am). How can I best accomplish this?

Update: The list of strings is composed of "startTime" + " - " + "endTime", so each entry in the list looks like:

```
6/10/2014 8:00:00 AM - 6/10/2014 8:30:00 AM
6/10/2014 8:30:00 AM - 6/10/2014 9:00:00 AM
etc...
```

Comment: There are several different ways depending on your implementation. Have you tried anything at all yet?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what your `List<String>` for times looks like?

Comment: I have updated my question to include more details about the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering collections in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by using a bit of lambda expressions.
Say your list of times is called:

```
times
```

then using the where clause, we can then get all the times after now by using:

```
List<string> ordered = times.Where(o => DateTime.Parse(o.Split('-')[1]) > DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

This basically parses each element in your 'times' list into a DateTIme type and then sees if it is after the current DateTime.

Comment: That's really slick and is almost perfect, however because it's evaluating both DateTime objects on either side of "-" it's still returning some unusable times. For instance if it's 9:15am, you'd still see an item indicating you're available from 9:00 - 9:30 because 9:30 isn't in the past.

To fix this, you'd just need to evaluate times on the left of the hyphen character. How could your expression be re-written to do that?

Comment: You would change `o.Split('-')[1]` to `o.Split('-')[0]` to evaluate the left hand time

Answer (score 1):

Using `LinQ` is usually the easiest way to filter a collection. Clearly however, this is going to be far more difficult if you stick with `string` values, so I'm going to look at this from a different angle - just recreating the collection each two hours. In this case, the filtering would be unnecessary... try something like this:

```
List<DateTime> validDates = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
for (int index = 0; index < 48; index++)
{
    if (startTime > DateTime.Now)
    {
        validDates.Add(startTime);
    }
    startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(30);
}
```

I'll leave it up to you how you want to populate your `string` values from these valid `DateTime` instances.