# Read objects from left to right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a C# Script in Unity, which detects all visible objects. Now I would like to output them from left to right, as how they are positioned in the scene. Each objects has a number and yet the script outputs the objects by ascending order.

**My idea:**

I thought about a `for-loop` which goes along the horizontal field of view. First calculating the horizontal FOV by:

```
private static float horizontalFOV() {
    float radAngle = Camera.main.fieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    float radHFOV = 2 * Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Tan(radAngle / 2) * Camera.main.aspect);
    float hFOV = Mathf.Rad2Deg * radHFOV;

    return hFOV;
}
```

And creating the loop by:

```
public static string OutputVisibleRenderers (List<Renderer> renderers) {
    float hFov = horizontalFOV ();

    if (null == renderers)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException ("renderers are null");

    for (int i = 0; i < hFov; i++) {
        foreach (var renderer in renderers) {
                if (IsVisible (renderer)) {
                myList.Add (renderer.name);
            }
        }
    }
    string itemsInOneLine = string.Join ("-", myList.ToArray());
    myList.Clear ();
    print (itemsInOneLine);
    print ("--------------------------------------------------");
    return itemsInOneLine;
}
```

But unfortunally this doesn't work. So how could I read all objects from left to right?

Comment: Are you getting an error or is `renderers` empty or are they not getting added to the list?

Comment: More information on how it "doesn't work" would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the list is created, but all names (which are numbers) are added by ascending order. And I want them to be added by "position" order, from left to right.

Comment: You need to sort them, you can use each object's `transform.position` as the value to sort on.

Comment: @Draco18s how may I realize it?

Comment: I don't use Unity, so sorry if I'm missing something, but it seems that although in the outer `for` loop You look from left to right, You don't use this information inside the loop. The inner loop just checks if each renderer is visible and adds it to the list, so they probably appear in the output list in the order they are put in the `renderers` collection.

Comment: In order to sort the objects from left to right, You should probably calculate their on-screen coordinates and then use them for sorting. To calculate this, You can use WorldToScreenPoint method (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html). I've found some suggestions that may be helpful here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/49943/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-on-screen-render-size.html. 
To sort it, You can use SortedList structure `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Unity, so sorry if I'm missing something, but it seems that although in the outer `for` loop You look from left to right, You don't use this information inside the loop. The inner loop just checks if each renderer is visible and adds it to the list, so they probably appear in the output list in the order they are put in the `renderers` collection.

In order to sort the objects from left to right, You should probably calculate their on-screen coordinates and then use them for sorting. To calculate this, You can use [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) method. I've found some suggestions that may be helpful here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/49943/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-on-screen-render-size.html.

To sort the objects, You can use `SortedList` class described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx.
After calculating on-screen coordinates for each object, just add it to the list with on-screen X coordinate as the key and the list will automatically keep the objects ordered.

Comment: I'm not sure what You mean. Please explain why `Bound` not being static is a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `renderers` is a List, you could use the `List.Sort` method and use the dot product to sort the objects from left to right.

I've made a script that works here, give it a try

```
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<Renderer> renderers ;

    private void Start()
    {
        var sortedRenderers = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Renderer>( renderers ) ;
        sortedRenderers.Sort( SortLeftToRight ) ;

        for( int i = 0 ; i < sortedRenderers.Count ; ++i )
            Debug.Log( sortedRenderers[i].name ) ;

    }
    private int SortLeftToRight( Renderer r1, Renderer r2 )
    {
        Transform camTransform = Camera.main.GetComponent<Transform>(); // You can optimize if you cache the transform of the camera
        Vector3 axis = camTransform.right ; 
        Transform t1 = r1.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
        Transform t2 = r2.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
        float dot1 = Vector3.Dot( axis, t1.position - camTransform.position );
        float dot2 = Vector3.Dot( axis, t2.position - camTransform.position );

        if( Mathf.Abs( dot1 - dot2 ) < 0.001f )
            return 0 ;

        return dot1 < dot2 ? -1 : 1 ;
    }
```

[image: SortRenderers]

**Useful links :**

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingVectorArithmetic.html

Comment: In my code, I don't check if the renderer is visible. Check this question to filter the renderer if they are visible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp