# Find object in list with specific value

Tags: c#, list, class, object

I have this class:

```
public class Person
{
    public String name;
    public int score;
    public float multiplier;

    public Person(String nameID)
    {
        name = nameID;
        score = 0;
        multiplier = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

And I have a List containing these classes:

```
private List<Person> _people;
```

Is there some way I could get a score using a name, like this?

```
_people.GetScore("example name"); // return the score of the class containing that name?
```

Comment: from where did `GetScore` came ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering collections in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal that was just an example of what I wanted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
_people.FirstOrDefault(c => c.name == "example name")?.score;
```

Just don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` to your `using` directives first. Also note that you need to use [*Null-conditional*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator(`?.`) also, that is used to *test for null before performing a member access* (`score` in this case)
Also it would be better to use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) instead of fields:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: And if the name is not found in the list?

Comment: @Rotem Thanks. Check my updated answer and `?` operator.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thanks, I'll look into Linq. I'm new to C#, what does the { get; set; } do?

Comment: @JamesA They are Auto-Implemented Properties. Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq query to get the result:

```
int result = _people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == "example name").score
```

If _people list contains multiple records with name "example name" then you can use where clause and get all results from the list

```
var results = _people.Where(p => p.name == "example name");
    foreach(var r in results)
        Console.WriteLine(r.score);
```

Now you can iterate through the results to get all scores

Here is the implementation: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NhWPKQ)

Comment: `Where` returns a filtered `IEnumerable`, not a single result.

Comment: Thanks @Rotem, I made corrections to it. FirstOrDefault is more precise than where

Comment: @Rotem, I used `FirstOrDefault` as well as `Where` clause. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score -1):

You can you `Single` method of `IEnumerable`

```
var score = _people.Single(p => p.name == "example name").score
```

Comment: a `Single` methond can only be used if there is one and only one element in the sample by it's predicate

Comment: I thought that `name` is a primary key for a Player. Can exist two player with the same name?

Comment: Sometimes they can. So there may be no players with that name, because, for example, he has not yet appeared in the game.