# C# Linq on a list of dictionaries to filter it

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, dictionary

I'm having a problem not knowing how to use LINQ properly.

I have a `List` of `Dictionaries(string, object)` like this:

```
[0] -> "field1":1500, "field2":"dog", "field3":"blue"
[1] -> "field1":1700, "field2":"cat", "field3":"brown"
[2] -> "field1":1500, "field2":"horse", "field3":"white"
[3] -> "field1":1900, "field2":"cow", "field3":"black"
```

I need to get from this a `List` of `Dictionaries` with only the Dictionaries that have the `"field1"` set to `1500`, so the output should be:

```
[0] -> "field1":1500, "field2":"dog", "field3":"blue"
[1] -> "field1":1500, "field2":"horse", "field3":"white"
```

I tried doing it like this but I'm sure I'm nowhere near the right answer.

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> output = input.SelectMany(r => r).Where(r => (r.Key == "field1") && (r.Value == 1500)).ToList();
```

Please can you suggest me a solution for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "I'm nowhere near the right answer" Why do you suppose this? What is your result you get?

Comment: Instead of using collections as properties learn to implement custom classes

Comment: `List<Dictionary<string, object>> filteredDictionaries = dictionaries.Where(dictionary => dictionary.ContainsKey("field1") && (int)dictionary["field1"] == 1500).ToList();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering collections in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev That's way to generic to be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result = 
    dicts.Where(
        d => d.TryGetValue("field1", out object value) && value is int i && i == 1500
    ).ToList();
```

This picks out all the dictionaries in the list that have a field called `field1` (via the `d.TryGetValue()`) and where that value is also `1500`.

Note that because the dictionary contains `object` and not `int`, you need to check if the value is `int` using `is int i`.

Also note that this syntax uses the C# version 7 or later.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was perfect for what I needed!

Comment: @Downvoter: I'd be interested in the reason for the downvote for this answer. How can I improve this answer? Downvotes without explanation are not particularly useful...

Answer (score 3):

Whilst you could write your entire model as a collection of collections (of collections...) it´s merely a good idea as it´s impossible to understand and to maintain. You should definitly create your own classes, e.g.:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create instances of those types and don´t have to mess up with `object`. E.g.

```
var m = new MyType { Field1 = 1500, Field2 = "dog", Field3 = "blue" };
```

You can also put this into a collection:

```
var myList = new[] { m };
```

and even select elements from that list that satisfy your condition:

```
var result = myList.Where(x => x.Field1 == 1500);
```

Notice that `Field1` is of type integer, so you get a compiler-error if you´re comparing the value with `"MyValue"` for example. In your solution the dicitonaries values are of type `object`, so you could store *anything* into `Field1`, not just numbers.

Apart from all this you should also use some meaningful names for your members, e.g. `Color` instead of `Field2` and `Animal` instead of `Field2`.