# search by filter in streamreader c#

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, streamreader

I want to search  by filter this Data Grid View I have searched so many time for  a way to do that  but nun of the solutions I found worked with my code 
( this is the  code I use to load the data grid view )

```
static public string APP_FOLDER = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Tools/Admin Tool/");
public string fileItem = ("Item.txt");

public class itemInterface
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }

    public itemInterface(string key, string value)
    {
        Code = key;
        Item = value;
    }
    public itemInterface(string[] value)
    {
        Code = value[0];
        Item = value[1];
    }
}

static public void UpdateItemDataGridView(DataGridView dgv, List<itemInterface> pList)
{
    dgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    dgv.DataSource = pList;
    dgv.Columns[0].Width = 70;
    dgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<itemInterface> pList = new List<itemInterface>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(APP_FOLDER + fileItem, Encoding.UTF8, true))
    {
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            itemInterface l = new itemInterface(s.Split('\t'));
            pList.Add(l);
        }
    }
    UpdateItemDataGridView(dataGridView2, pList);
}
```

Comment: Where are you filtering? `pList` isn't being filtered after initialization. Use `linq` or a `for loop` to filter as needed.

Comment: sorry but I did not understand
I want to filter the plist to fined a specific item by textbox

Comment: Give an example and I'll post an answer.

Comment: How about [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp)? Or do the filtering in a DataView (recommended)

Comment: it's a data grade view that view a table this table have 2 columns  from text file  and I want to search that table for a specific item  
looks like that https://imgur.com/a/AjL0dOw

Comment: Clearly a case for loading into a DataSource and then filteering via a DataView so you won't have to reload from the StreamReader. Look into [dataview.rowfilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I did't understand what to do from the link you sent ( can I send you the project  source and you help me with making the search by filter work

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiLNiCo4tuKyhuJIeatfbqcL09lzDg

Comment: I found a code  but I don't know where to add it 
pList.FindAll(i => i.Item.ToLower().Contains("Plann".ToLower()));

Answer (score 1):

I  fined the  way  to  do the search  the code  is

```
 List<itemInterface> pList = new List<itemInterface>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(APP_FOLDER + fileItem, Encoding.UTF8, true))
    {
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            itemInterface l = new itemInterface(s.Split('\t'));

            pList.Add(l);

        }
    }

    var pSearch = pList.FindAll(i => i.Item.ToLower().Contains(textBox12.Text.ToLower()));
    UpdateItemDataGridView(dataGridView2, pSearch);
```