# Remove an Item from C# Enum List

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I am storing a list of Choices of Enum values and my Enum looks like below

```
enum OrderDay 
{
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Wednesday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
};
List<OrderDay> DayChoices;  //List stores the selected values
```

Initially  the List contains 3 values

```
{
Wednesday,
Friday,
Saturday
}
```

How to filter out a specific value from this list and makes list as

```
{
    Wednesday,
    Friday
}
```

This is the code i was trying , but ended up as build error.    Trying to recreate the list without the given day value

```
private async Task OnChipDayEnumClose(OrderDay val)
{ 
    DayChoices = DayChoices.Where(s => s != val).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You should also paste the "build error"

Comment: `List<T>` has a `RemoveAll` method that takes in a predicate... you don't need linq

Comment: Meanwhile, `OnChipDayEnumClose` doesn't need to be async. It serves no purpose.

Comment: What happened to Tuesday and Thursday :) Also if you don't know, there's already a [DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=net-6.0) enum.

Comment: Do you have a List of the filtered options? Use the Except Method to get the filtered List

Comment: @zaggler I used Days as an enum easy to convey the problem i am facing . The real enum is a different one Thank you

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you managed to sort it using Remove method of List

Comment: @Sebastian I wouldn't have thought that considering your comment in your post, `my Enum looks like below`... thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering collections in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp) includes `linq`, `RemoveAll`, `yield` etc. solutions....

Comment: I might be being a bit thick, but why is this not just `Remove(Saturday)`?

Comment: `OnChipDayEnumClose` is declared to return a `Task` but it does not in fact return a `Task`...

Answer (score 3):

You have to re-assign  filtered collection after filtering, try this, it was tested in VS and working properly

```
List<OrderDay> dayChoices = new List<OrderDay> { OrderDay.Wednesday, OrderDay.Friday, OrderDay.Saturday };

dayChoices = OnChipDayEnumClose(dayChoices, OrderDay.Wednesday);


private List<OrderDay> OnChipDayEnumClose(List<OrderDay> dayChoices, OrderDay val)
{
    return dayChoices.Where(s => s != val).ToList();
}
```

or  an alternative variant, thanks to @zaggler

```
private void OnChipDayEnumClose(List<OrderDay> dayChoices, OrderDay val)
{
    dayChoices.RemoveAll(s => s == val);
}
```